# How to get output eventemitter boolean value in parent ts file?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular12

I have below code in my child component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-child'
})
export class ChildComponent {

    @Output()
    dataDeleted: EventEmitter<boolean>;

    constructor() {
        this.dataDeleted = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
    }

    delete() {
        this.dataDeleted.emit(true);
    }
}
```

I tried using `@Input() dataDeleted: boolean;` in parent ts file. but it's not working.

Comment: Please let us know what you haven't found in this page before posting: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Parent component:

1. Add event listener to the child selector. The `$event` is an angular specific variable which is a generic name for what ever you emitted from the child component, in your case it holds the boolean value.

HTML:

```html
<app-child (dataDeleted)="onDataDeleted($event)"></app-child>
```

2. Add a method to call when event is emitted.

TS:

```
onDataDeleted(val:boolean)
{
 
}
```

You can read [this guide](https://duncanhunter.gitbook.io/angular-and-ngrx/7.-listen-to-child-component-events)

Comment: Hi @ayala. Thank you for answer. `test: boolean; onDataDeleted(val:boolean) { this.test = val;}`. This `this.test` how can I make globally accessible in TS file?

Comment: Why do you need global accessible? please share more details

Comment: On basis of that value. I need to change the value in another function.

Comment: Call the another function in onDataDeleted method